# Is it possible to serialize two forms in one ajax function?

Tags: php, ajax, serialization

I need to serialize two forms in the same ajax function with one call. I have tried the following but it just serialize the last one.

```
                function sssssss2(page){
            var form1 = document.myform1;
            var form2 = document.myform2;
                            var dataString1 = $(form1).serialize() + '&page=' + page;
            var dataString2 = $(form2).serialize() + '&page=' + page;
                $.ajax
                ({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "load_data.php",
                    data: {dataString1, dataString2}
                    success: function(ccc)
                    {
                     $("#container").html(ccc);
                    }
                });
            }
```

It doesn't work. How may I serialize both of them within the same function?

Comment: Why do you even have 2 forms?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
var dataString1 = $(form1).serialize() + '&page=' + page +$(form2).serialize();
data: {dataString1}
```

Comment: I don't think this would work. What if forms contain same input names?

Comment: Its OP's problem that has the same fields in both forms

Comment: Then he have to urlencode it and put to separated variables or (better) change forms to send data in separated arrays.